# dot-dot-dot mechanism inside purrr functions

Tags: r, purrr

Let me start with a toy dataset

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(13)
X<-matrix(rnorm(120),20,6) %>% data.frame %>% set_colnames(LETTERS[1:5])
```

and a toy function that draws 6 scatterplots: one for each column of `X` against random vector.

```
foo<-function(X){
  win.graph(5,5)
  par(mfcol=c(3,2))
  par(mar=c(5,4,.1,.1))
  X %>% iwalk(~plot(.x, rnorm(20), xlab=.y, ylab='Random'))
}

foo(X)
```

[image: foo]

Now I add dot-dot-dot mechanism to it:

```
foo<-function(X,...){
  win.graph(5,5)
  par(mfcol=c(3,2))
  par(mar=c(5,4,.1,.1))
  X %>% iwalk(~plot(.x, rnorm(20), xlab=.y, ylab='Random',...))
}
```

And now `foo(X)` results with an error `Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value`. Also `foo(X, pch=2)` gives the same error.

Why is that? Why `iwalk` seems to put any additional parameter passed via `...` to `xlim`? How to change above code to be able to pass additional parameters via `...`?

**EDIT**

I tried `tidyeval` approach with `quos` function and `!!!` operator:

```
foo<-function(X, ...){
  win.graph(5,5)
  par(mfcol=c(3,2))
  par(mar=c(5,4,.1,.1))
  vars<-quos(...)
  X %>% iwalk(~plot(.x, rnorm(20),xlab=.y, ylab='Random', !!! vars))
}
```

Now both `foo(X)` and `foo(X, pch=2)` result with `Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this `do.call`

```
foo <- function(X, ...){
     v1 <- c(...)

  win.graph(5,5)
  par(mfcol=c(3,2))
  par(mar=c(5,4,.1,.1))
   X %>%
      iwalk(~ {args <- list(xlab = .y, ylab = 'Random')
               args[names(v1)] <- v1
           do.call(plot, c(list(x = .x, y = rnorm(20)), args))            

               }) 
  }

foo(X)
foo(X, cex = 2)
foo(X, pch = 2)
foo(X, cex = 2, pch = 2)
foo(X, cex = 2, pch = 2, col = 2)
```

gives the output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution (+1). It works, however, I was thinking of something more `tidyverse`-like. Please see edit I made to my question.